# Calling get property from a class to another class

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

So anybody please tell me how can I play a video when i click on a particular song in list box.I have parsed the RSS feed and displayed all videos in listbox..

I have a class named Songsdetails with few properties

```
  public class Songsdetails

{

      public string songname { get; set; }
      public string songpic { get; set; }
      public string songurl { get; set; }
      public string songcode { get; set; }
      public string songdescr { get; set; }
      public string songtitletags { get; set; }
      public string songmetatags { get; set; }
      public string songmetadesc { get; set; }
      public string songdate { get; set; }

}
```

I am calling this song code to Videopage.Xaml.cs by following process.But songcode was not called.Null was present in variable.

```
namespace videosongs
{
    public partial class Videopage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public Videopage()
        {
        InitializeComponent();

        Songsdetails songdetails=new Songsdetails();
        string code = songdetails.songcode;
        string video = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+code;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(video);
        this.webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(video));

        }
```

Please anybody help how to get the songcode.I am not understanding why songcode was not coming.
By this song code videos to be played in emulator.
Please anybody help were the mistake was.And how to get the songcode values.
Thankyou.

```
namespace videosongs
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // is there network connection available
        if (!System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No network connection available!");
            return;
        }
        // start loading XML-data
        WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.teluguone.com/videosongs/videoSongsXml.php?cat_id=6", UriKind.Absolute);
        downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(VideosongsDownloaded);
        downloader.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
    }


    void VideosongsDownloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Result == null || e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error downloading the XML-file!");
        }
        else
        {

            //Deserialize if download succeeds

            {

                XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Videosongs));
                Videosongs videosongs = (Videosongs)serializer.Deserialize(document.CreateReader());
                videosongList.ItemsSource = videosongs.Collection;

            }

        }

    }

    private void videosongList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox listBox = sender as ListBox;

        if (listBox != null && listBox.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            Songsdetails song = (Songsdetails)listBox.SelectedItem;

            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Videopage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }

    }
}
```

}
 **videosongs class**

```
   namespace videosongs
    {
    [XmlRoot("videosongs")]
    public class Videosongs
   {
        [XmlElement("songsdetails")]
        public ObservableCollection<Songsdetails> Collection { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Where is `songdetails.songcode` set?

Comment: You're initializing `songdetails` the line before you're calling `songcode` - where should the value for `songcode` come from?

Comment: I have multiple values for songcode in RSS feed.And when i click on a particular song that has to be played by getting songcode.

Comment: Hint: your code doesn't mention an RSS feed anywhere. Where are you expecting it to be used?

Comment: I have already parsed RSS feed and displayed videosongs in listBox.And Videopage .Xaml.cs is  a navigated page in which code for playing videosongs was written

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're expecting `songdetails` to be populated with the `songcode` from some control in the xaml? Could you post your xaml?

Comment: When I click on a particular song in listbox it should be navigated to other page get the songcode from rss feed and start playing.

Comment: `Songsdetails songdetails=new Songsdetails(); string code = songdetails.songcode;` creates a new `Songsdetails`, since you don't have a constructor, all properties will have default values, which means `null` for `String`. If you need a *specific* `Songsdetails` object, you need to construct it with parameters or built it elsewhere and not create a new one.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i get the songcode from rss feed and play videos.I was on this from many weeks.

Comment: So anybody please tell me how can I play a video when i click on a particular song in list box.I have parsed the RSS feed and displayed in listbox..

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good practice to define a constructor for the data carrier classes that you create. This will avoid the Null Pointer Exception. Also as said by @germi, in this code the mail problem is that you are not setting it. So how can you use it?

Thanks
Arun

Comment: Ya sir,but inorder to set I have multiple values in rss feed.And I was thinking how to set those multiple values.This is the situation were videos in listbox have to be played when i click on particular song.I am not undestanding how to play.Please tell me how can I set those multiple values..This is the RSS feed i parsed and displayed in listbox
http://www.teluguone.com/videosongs/videoSongsXml.php?cat_id=6

Comment: If that is the case that you has use a List of the Songsdetails objects. You can set the values independently for each object and then read the values using a foreach loop.

Comment: Then when I click on a particular song  that particular only should be played and stopped.If  I use foreach loop, when I click on a song from first song it starts playing and plays continuosly until all complets.Then it will be of no use for me.

Comment: Then maintain the list of object as such. Display only the song names and song pic. Based on the click, call a method to get the URL from the list and then play the song.

Comment: If we pass the direct url the code will be static.If the feed was changed code will be failed.I need it to be dynamic.Can u help me.

Comment: It will be dynamic. Because on each load you will be filling in your list of object and then populating it right? So based on the values on each load the URL will change. It will remain dynamic.

Comment: In RSS feed direct url is not given.We have to write the common part for every url and add getsongcode.Which is like "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+(here i have to get sogngcode).This is actual problem I was facing.I am not knowing how to call songcode to this page from songsdetails class.Thanku